# Yammer - Users login stopped working

Tags: oauth, yammer

A significant number of users are getting the error message of 'GetAccessToken - Unauthorized error: Your network is not allowed to request an OAuth token for this Application' whilst trying to log in to our application.

I have checked and tested, and they are accessing the correct network with the right credentials. This is happening to almost every person, so I don't believe this to be a coincidence.

This has only begun to happen in the past 24-36 hours. Are there any suggestions as to why this error is occurring, has something changed that I may have missed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of possible scenarios:

1. It is likely that the new simplified SSO is rolling out for these
   users, which means they will use their O365 credentials to login to
   Yammer from now on. Every user will need to reauth external apps (I
   had to for our own apps also when this change occurred for us last
   week).
2. Tokens also can expire when user's passwords expire, so if
   they have a mandatory time interval to reset this could trigger an en masse need to reauth
3. Make sure your JS Origins are specified in your app details if you are using the Login with Yammer button and/or the JS SDK. http://naomimoneypenny.com/2015/02/11/yammer-apps-javascript-origins-update/

There isn't clear and definitive guidance regrettably from Yammer as to why and when tokens expire. Just that they do e.g. from https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/oauth-2

> Once the token expires, you will need to re-run the steps above to generate a new code and access_token.